# Unnecessary files are generated when rails application is launched

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin16]

This began to occur after tweaking the settings around `--binstubs`.

The following are generated files.

```
    bin/brakeman
    bin/bundle-audit
    bin/bundler-audit
    bin/byebug
    bin/cap
    bin/capify
    bin/chromedriver-helper
    bin/chromedriver-update
    bin/coderay
    bin/console
    bin/dotenv
    bin/fission
    bin/fog
    bin/foreman
    bin/generate-api
    bin/haml
    bin/htmldiff
    bin/httpclient
    bin/ldiff
    bin/listen
    bin/maruku
    bin/marutex
    bin/nokogiri
    bin/pry
    bin/rackup
    bin/rbvmomish
    bin/restclient
    bin/rspec
    bin/rubocop
    bin/ruby-parse
    bin/ruby-rewrite
    bin/sass
    bin/sass-convert
    bin/scss
    bin/sprockets
    bin/thor
    bin/tilt
    bin/unicorn
    bin/unicorn_rails
    bin/whenever
    bin/wheneverize
```

The following is the message on the terminal.

```
20:39:07 web.1  | Beginning in Rails 4, Rails ships with a `rails` binstub at ./bin/rails that
20:39:07 web.1  | should be used instead of the Bundler-generated `rails` binstub.
20:39:07 web.1  | 
20:39:07 web.1  | If you are seeing this message, your binstub at ./bin/rails was generated by
20:39:07 web.1  | Bundler instead of Rails.
20:39:07 web.1  | 
20:39:07 web.1  | You might need to regenerate your `rails` binstub locally and add it to source
20:39:07 web.1  | control:
20:39:07 web.1  | 
20:39:07 web.1  |  rails app:update:bin           # Bear in mind this generates other binstubs
20:39:07 web.1  |                                 # too that you may or may not want (like yarn)
20:39:07 web.1  | 
20:39:07 web.1  | If you already have Rails binstubs in source control, you might be
20:39:07 web.1  | inadverently overwriting them during deployment by using bundle install
20:39:07 web.1  | with the --binstubs option.
20:39:07 web.1  | 
20:39:07 web.1  | If your application was created prior to Rails 4, here's how to upgrade:
20:39:07 web.1  | 
20:39:07 web.1  |   bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
20:39:07 web.1  |   rails app:update:bin          # Use the new Rails executables
20:39:07 web.1  |   git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control
20:39:07 web.1  | 
20:39:07 web.1  | You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.
20:39:07 web.1  | 
20:39:07 web.1  | When you install a gem whose executable you want to use in your app,
20:39:07 web.1  | generate it and add it to source control:
20:39:07 web.1  | 
20:39:07 web.1  |   bundle binstubs some-gem-name
20:39:07 web.1  |   git add bin/new-executable
20:39:07 web.1  |
```

Which setting should I change to fix it?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing